# MS Access - Web Browser Control - How to open linked document/url in the same frame as it was clicked

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have added a Web Browser Control to a Microsoft Access form. I have it navigating to a page with additional links that I can click on. My problem is that when I click a link, it opens the link in my local web browser (Edge).  I want the new page to stay in my MS Access application and open in the same Web Browser Control.

The website's HTML link basically looks like this `<a href="#" target="_blank">` which opens a new window (in my case a whole new browser), and I don't have the ability to edit that webpage.

Would anyone happen to have a solution for me? Thank you so much!

Comment: When the page is loaded into the control you should be able to use VBA to switch any links so that `target` is "_self" and not "_blank".  Or you should be able to use `removeAttribute('target')` on the links, since "_self" is the default I think.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you for the response! Any chance you can help me out with the VBA code? I've only been working with MS Access for a couple of months now. I've gone through 10 chapters in the Access 2016 Bible and have gotten 75% through a MS Access course on uDemy. I've been learning a lot, but this one has so far stumped me. I did search for the removeAttribute in my Access 2016 Bible and found nothing. I also did some web searching and am not finding exactly what I need. Any additional guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can try it out if you can share the URL (I don't have Access but the Web Browser control is common across other Office apps I think)

Comment: Thanks, Tim! I can't share the URL because it can't be accessed outside of our company's network. No worries, I'll do my best to figure it out if no one else chimes in. :) Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the VBA code I used to get result I wanted. I did get help from another outside source.
The Web Browser Control has a name of WebBrowser0 in the example below.

```
Dim mParentURL As String

Private Sub Form_Load()
    
    mParentURL = Me.WebBrowser0.ControlSource

End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser0_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)

    WebBrowser0.Object.Document.Body.innerhtml = Replace(WebBrowser0.Object.Document.Body.innerhtml, "_blank", "_self", , , vbTextCompare)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example using a URL which contains a link with `Target="_self"`

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "https://www.dofactory.com/html/target/blank"
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Dim doc As Object, links As Object, link As Object, t
    
    Set doc = WebBrowser1.Document
    Set links = doc.getelementsbytagname("A") 'get all links
    
    For Each link In links                      'loop over links
        t = link.getAttribute("target")         'read the "target" attribute
        If Not IsNull(t) Then                   'has a target ?
            If t = "_blank" Then                'target is "_blank" ?
                link.removeAttribute "target"   'unset the target
                Debug.Print "Removed _blank"
            End If
        End If
    Next link
End Sub
```

You likely won't find any HTML Document Object Model methods in your VBA language guide: these belong to the "web stuff" sphere and to a different set of COM references.

Comment: Hi, Tim! Thank you for the reply and the code! :) I'll have to look a bit more into this tomorrow. I did try your code with very slight modifications. It was still opening the page links in Microsoft Edge. I may have done something wrong but it's almost the end of my work day and time to wrap things up. I'll look at this again tomorrow. Thanks again!